# Specify popup size for a Dotnetopenauth OpenID Provider

Tags: openid, single-sign-on, dotnetopenauth, openid-provider

I am implementing a SSO solution for a controlled set of web sites using Dotnetopenauth. It's really cool once you get the hang of it.

I am using the SelectorProviderButton on the RP side, as this handles all the popup stuff automatically. However, the size of the popup is huge - basically the size of a full web page, and thus obscures the RP page behind it. I have put a javascript set size on the OP login page, but the user can actually see it busy resizing.

So the question is, can the size of the popup be specified somewhere when using the SelectorProviderButton  (either on RP or OP), so that it is of manageable dimensions, such as when calling google, yahoo etc?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dimensions of the popup are hard-coded because the [OpenID UI extension spec](http://svn.openid.net/repos/specifications/user_interface/1.0/trunk/openid-user-interface-extension-1_0.html#anchor4) specifies what it should be.  The reason for this is the OP needs to know what they can expect the size of the window is that they would appear in to guarantee a good user experience for *your* users.

The spec actually asks for a 450x500 window, but Yahoo deviates in creating UI that only looks good in 500x500 and said they were going to get the spec updated to reflect that (which they've yet to do).  DotNetOpenAuth opens 500x500px popups as a result.

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for your reply and the work done on the library, it is really good. However, it does not seem to be opening a 500x500 popup, it is much larger than that. You can see this if you use an OpenIdSelecor and SelectorProviderButton on a RP site to open your sample WebRingSSOProvider (with it set to Forms auth, of course). It opens the 500x500 when you hit google or Yahoo however. Perhaps there is a setting that I have missed to enable the correct sizing of popups on a provider implemented with DotNetOpenAuth?

Comment: Ah, that remind me of a provision the library makes.  The 500x500 size is only used when the OP advertises that it supports popup windows.  Without that properly advertised at the OP, the DNOA RP will open up an even bigger window to try to ensure a good experience for the user.  So if you control the OP as well, you can properly advertise support for the popup window to solve this.  See http://svn.openid.net/repos/specifications/user_interface/1.0/trunk/openid-user-interface-extension-1_0.html#anchor7 (section 7) of the UI spec on how to do this.